# DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable - The record ... specified on this form or report does not exist

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, vba, startup, public

Let me start by saying I am not at all familiar with Access or VBA.  However, I am the IT guy and at some point someone created an MS Access database that does a thing and now I have to support it.

We have a database that upon opening deletes any old data and re-runs the external query that makes this application work.  Occasionally whatever state the program exited out in that table already does not exist.  This causes MS Access to hang on the delete line and I have to run the debugger, comment out the DoCmd.DeleteObject line, re run, and then un-comment the line to let the user continue with their day.

I want to add in some sort of conditional statement, but anything I've been able to google in terms of If...Then statements or 'TableExist' type functions always causes an error to be thrown that I haven't defined the function.  My best guess is I'm nesting this incorrectly or I'm not calling some sort of external function correctly, but as I said my VBA knowledge is extremely limited.

This code executes on startup:

```
Public Function Startup() As Integer

    DoCmd.Close acForm, "soLookup"
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "sales_order"
    DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "Import-sales_order"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "soLookup"

End Function
```

Its the

```
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "sales_order"
```

Line that causes things to fail.

I've attempted to restructure this several times based on several examples I had found, but I'll only bother with one below

```
Public Function Startup() As Integer

    DoCmd.Close acForm, "soLookup"
    If TableExists("sales_orders") Then
      DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "sales_orders"
    Else    
      'Do nothing
    End If 
    DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "Import-sales_order"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "soLookup"

End Function
```

Nothing I seem to try seems to give me any result other than an error of some sort.  All I want to do is add a conditional statement to this 'Startup' bit that checks if the "sales_order" table even if exists, and if it doesn't, then to just move on to the next comment and forget the DoCmd.DeleteObject.  How can I achieve this functionality?!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TableExists` function is not a standard function in Access. You need to define it yourself.

There are two main ways to define such a function, by trying and error trapping, or by iterating through all tables and checking names.

Way 1 (error trapping):

```
Public Function TableExists(TableName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    TableExists = CurrentDb.TableDefs(TableName).Name = TableName
End Function
```

Way 2 (iterating collection):

```
Public Function TableExists(TableName As String) As Boolean
    Dim td As DAO.TableDef
    For Each td In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If td.Name = TableName Then
            TableExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Define either of these functions in a public module, and your last approach should work

Answer (score 0):

I will instead modify the query to import the source data into a new table (sales_orders), which will overwrite existing data when the query runs and so I don't have to delete the table and have additional check for `TableExists`

[image]